# An inequality for a holomorphic $f\colon\mathbb H \to D$ with $f(z_0) = f'(z_0) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function from $H=\{z \in \mathbb C : \operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$ to $D=\{z \in \mathbb C : |z|<1\}$. Suppose that $f(z_0)=f'(z_0)=0$.

Show that:
\[
|f(z)| \leq \frac{|z-z_0|^2}{|z-\overline{z}_0|^2} \quad\text{and}\quad |f''(z_0)| \leq \frac{1}{2|\operatorname{Im}(z_0)|^2}
\]

Thanks everyone for your help!!

Comment: What have you tried? In my experience, questions that show some effort beyond a reproduction of an exercise get more attention. If you've tried something and it didn't work, it's okay and even desirable to mention that. My gut reaction is to use some conformal mapping to get a map $D \to D$ and then apply [Schwarz or Shwarz–Pick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma), but I don't have time to pursue this at the moment. Hopefully someone else will. Welcome, by the way!

Comment: Hey Dylan! First of all thanks for the greeting! I just tried to call $g(z)=f(z)/|z-z_0|^2$ and using the maximum modulus principle as when you demonstrate that $|f(z)|<|z|$ when f goes from D to D...it worked for demonstrating that $|f(z)|<|z|^2$, but I can't solve this one...

Comment: Should the $z$ in your second inequality be $z_0$?

Comment: yep, I mistyped

Comment: And by the way solving the first inequality the second becomes pretty obvious to me...the problem is the first one!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $g = f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ where $\varphi(z) = \dfrac{z - z_0}{z - \overline{z_0}}$,
and note that $g(w)/w^2$ has a removable singularity at $0$.